# How do I enable queue:work from live server?

Tags: laravel, queue, live

This one is working fine on my local server as I can run the command.

```
php artisan queue:work
```

**But how I can implement this on the live server?**
I am really stuck on that problem. But as I want to send the notification through mail. So, I am following to use that laravel default queue feature as it will make no delay and automatically do it's job. So, if you can help really appreciate that.

Advance Thanks..

//my .env configuration

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

[my jobs table from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGVFp.jpg)

//my NewScholarship Class

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewScholarship extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Queueable;



public $scholarship;


/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($scholarship)
{
    $this->scholarship = $scholarship;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hello, Subscriber!')
                ->subject('New Scholarship has been published')
                ->line('New Scholarship info has been published to our website')
                ->line('Titled as: '.$this->scholarship->title)
                ->line('To have a look click the button below')
                ->action('View details', url('s/details',$this->scholarship->slug))
                ->line('Thank you for your subscription!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea on production is same as development you should run queue:work but of course you can't ssh to your server every now and then and check if the command is still running, that is why you should use something like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html) as recommended by Laravel.

Here is a [quick introduction to supervisor in the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) 
Basically, if your server is debian, you should install the supervisor package by running:

`sudo apt-get install supervisor` after you ssh to your server

After the installation is complete, use vi vim or nano to access `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` and create a configuration file ex: `laravel-worker.conf`

Below is a sample configuration

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 #"home/forge/app.com/artisan" is the path to your project root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Notes from the laravel documentation:

> - You should ensure that the value of stopwaitsecs is greater than the number of seconds consumed by your longest running job. Otherwise, Supervisor may kill the job before it is finished processing.
> - In this example, the numprocs directive will instruct Supervisor to run 8 queue:work processes and monitor all of them, automatically restarting them if they fail.
> - You should change the queue:work sqs portion of the command directive to reflect your desired queue connection.

Note that this information is from the laravel documentation linked above

If your server is not debian please see the [official documentation of suppervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html)

> Once the configuration file has been created, you may update the Supervisor configuration and start the processes using the following commands:
>
> `sudo supervisorctl reread`
>
> `sudo supervisorctl update`
>
> `sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*`

Comment: sorry but i didn't find any terminal to run a command. Is there any way to run the command from local server? And I am a windows user.

Comment: do you have access to the live server ?

Comment: okay good, if the live server is a linux server follow my answer and it will work

Comment: my server operating system is linux. from where i can run this command?

Comment: how do you access your server ? if by ssh then you are in a terminal. start by installing suppervisor first then add the configuration file. then start suppervisor (i will edit my answer on how to start suppervisor)

Answer (score 0):

you should look for something called supervisor

check this for an example

[tutorial](https://www.coderomeos.org/laravel-queue-worker-and-supervisor-process-monitor)